# Canvas element not rendering on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas, materialize

I have a canvas element on my site that renders perfectly in the desktop browser as well as on Android devices, but will not render on iOS devices (iPad, iPhone)  - neither Safari nor Chrome on ios. I'm using Materialize as my CSS framework.

Is there something I need to add to my code?

[Here is live version](http://wesleylhandy.net)

```js
var next; //initialize for interval
 //paint random colored pattern on profile screen
 function paintCanvas() {

  const c = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  c.width = window.outerWidth;

  const width = c.width;
  const height = 612; //canvas height

  const min = 0;
  const max = width;
  const yMid = height/2;
  var y1 = yMid;
  var y2 = yMid;

  function getRandomColor(){

   let r = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
   let g = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
   let b = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
   let color = `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, 0.5)`;
   return color;
  }

  var x = 0;

  function paint() {

   if (x==(max/2)-2) {
    clearInterval(next);
   }
   ctx.lineWidth = 4; //sets width of line 
      ctx.strokeStyle = getRandomColor(); //assigns random color
      ctx.beginPath(); //start line
      ctx.moveTo(x,y1); //moves the origin
      ctx.lineTo(max-x,y2); //go to the bottom right corner
    ctx.moveTo(x, y2);
    ctx.lineTo(max-x, y1);
      ctx.stroke();
      
      if(y1==0) {
       x++;
      } else {
       y1--;
       y2++;
      }

     }

  next = setInterval(paint, 0.05);
 }

 paintCanvas();
```

```css
main {
 position: relative;
}

#canvas {
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<main id="#top" role="main">

  <canvas id="canvas" width="100%" height = "612px"></canvas>
  
</main>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem by enabling Web Inspector on my Ipad (Settings>>Safari>>Advanced) and then connecting to a friends Mac PC. Using Safari on the Mac, I was able to enable Web Inspector and thus view Apple's Developer Tools (Settings>>Advanced>>Show Develop Menu In Menu Bar).

I found that the width for my `<canvas>` element was returning to zero. This meant that `window.innerWidth` was either returning `0` or `null` and thus resizing my canvas to zero width rather than to the width of the device.

This led me to try using `screen.width` instead. This solved the problem. Since I know that `window.innerWidth` works on all other devices, I added a check on `navigator.platform` to use screen.width only on iOS devices.

```js
    var next; //initialize for interval
 //paint random colored pattern on profile screen
 function paintCanvas() {

  const c = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  
        //____________________________________________
        // ----------- FIX FOR THIS PROBLEM ----------
        //____________________________________________

        if ( navigator.platform != "iPad" && navigator.platform != "iPhone" && navigator.platform != "iPod" ) {
      c.width = window.outerWidth; 
            //I'll use window.innerWidth in production
     } else {
      c.width = screen.width;
     }

  const width = c.width;
  const height = 612; //canvas height

  const min = 0;
  const max = width;
  const yMid = height/2;
  var y1 = yMid;
  var y2 = yMid;

  function getRandomColor(){

   let r = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
   let g = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
   let b = Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
   let color = `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, 0.5)`;
   return color;
  }

  var x = 0;

  function paint() {

   if (x==(max/2)-2) {
    clearInterval(next);
   }
   ctx.lineWidth = 4; //sets width of line 
      ctx.strokeStyle = getRandomColor(); //assigns random color
      ctx.beginPath(); //start line
      ctx.moveTo(x,y1); //moves the origin
      ctx.lineTo(max-x,y2); //go to the bottom right corner
    ctx.moveTo(x, y2);
    ctx.lineTo(max-x, y1);
      ctx.stroke();
      
      if(y1==0) {
       x++;
      } else {
       y1--;
       y2++;
      }

     }

  next = setInterval(paint, 0.05);
 }

 paintCanvas();
```

```css
main {
 position: relative;
}

#canvas {
 position: absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<main id="#top" role="main">

  <canvas id="canvas" width="100%" height = "612px"></canvas>
  
</main>
```